# I want to call a rails function from a view and then keep the same view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to rails and this is my first stab at a real app so forgive my ignorance :)

I want to call a custom method(non-CRUD) from my main view, and want to reload the original page once the function goes through. This is the method:

```
def push
push_to_shopify

if Article.count == 0
  flash[:info] = "All posts pushed to Shopify."
  render :nothing => true
else
  redirect_to :back
end
end
```

push_to_shopify is a method I've defined in the controller's helper:

```
def push_to_shopify
    Article.each do |a|
    ShopifyAPI::Article.new(
        :title => a.title,
        :author => a.author,
        :body_html => a.body_html,
        :published_at => a.published_at,
        :tags => a.tags,
        :summary_html => a.summary_html,
        :blog_id => a.blog_id
        )
    Article.destroy(a.id)
    end
end
```

And this is how I'm trying to call it:

```
<%= link_to 'Push all articles to Shopify', '#', id: "push-link" %>

</div>

<script>
var callExecuter=function(){
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: articles_push_path
});

success:function(){
  window.location = "<%= calendars_url %>";
}

}

$(document).on("click","#push-link",callExecuter);
</script>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Rails way:**

Setting `remote: true` on your `link_to` is the easiest method. Check documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). Your link would look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Push all articles to Shopify', '#', id: "push-link", remote: true %>
```

The project source is to be found [here](https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs) and similar examples are to be found on the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to)

**Javascript way**

If you want to stick to your code you should simply use 
[`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) that prevents the normal action of clicking on link! So you would have something like this:

```
$(document).on("click","#push-link", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Your AJAX code
});
```